# XMLSerializer Deserialization - array element order

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

We are using XMLSerializer.Deserialize(XMLReader) on .Net 4.5 to deserialize XML into an Object Graph generated by xsd.exe.

I would like to know what the expected deserialization behavior is for an array which is annotated with the XMLElementAttribute - specifically with regard to ordering.  For example:

For the following property:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("GivenName")]
  public string[] GivenName {
 // get() and set() methods
}
```

And the following XML:

```
<root>
  <GivenName>One</GivenName>
  <GivenName>Two</GivenName>
  <GivenName>Three</GivenName>
</root>
```

Will this always deserialize as ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

So that the array order always matches the XML order

Also is there any documentation I can reference that clearly states this.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

**Yes Its deserialize same order.** Check the code sample code and output:

[image: Output]

```
 [System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class SampleClass
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 10)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 5)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("GivenName", Order = 15)]
    public string[] GivenNames { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = new string[3] { "One", "Two", "Three" };

        SampleClass TestObj = new SampleClass { Bar = "dsdfsdf", Foo = "test", GivenNames = names };
        XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SampleClass));
        // Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file
        TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\files\test.xml");
        SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, TestObj);
        // Cleanup
        WriteFileStream.Close();

        // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
        FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\files\test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        // Load the object saved above by using the Deserialize function
        SampleClass LoadedObj = (SampleClass)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);

        // Cleanup
        ReadFileStream.Close();


    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment below.  I am after an explicate documentation reference that states the order is retained.  The cost of loosing order in my situation (even in a small number of scenarios) is high.  I also have many test cases that demonstrate the ordering is generally respected, but I am after some amount of certainty whether it is in all cases or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can find some awesome information about it on msdn which is provide by microsoft.

[This is the "official" documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(v=vs.110).aspx)

The serialization is linear so you will alway get the same order normally.

Comment: I've looked through the documentation and can't find anything that states specifically the element order is respected when translated into an array.

In my situation there is a significant amount of business risk associated to the order being dropped even if it occurs in a small number of cases.  Consequently I am after a specific reference - (even if it is code) that either states the order is respected (or isn't)

I acknowledge the correct solution is to explicitly order with an ordinal attribute, but I do not own the interface and the cost of change is high.

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization Namespace
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization(v=vs.110).aspx
The order of deserialization relative to other objects in the graph is non-deterministic.
This is the only thing found.